# Using Moles without a testing framework

Tags: .net, delegates, runtime, instrumentation, moles

I would like to delegate every instance of DateTime.Now in my project. The project needs to be tested as a whole and unit testing will not be helpful in this case. I would like to do something like set DateTime.Now to a specific time or Add/Subtract minutes from the current date time and then have every DateTime.Now reference in the project pick up the redirected value. Is this possible with Microsoft Moles? Is there any way to run the entire project using    mole instrumentation?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is to stub the System.DateTime type, using dependency injection.  Retrofitting an IOC shouldn't take more than 30-60 minutes, tops.  You could fall back on using a 3rdd party utility, like Ninject.  However, its always best to do things the right way and code it in.

Using Moles or Fakes is something you really don't want to do, unless absolutely necessary (e.g. 3rd party APIs, etc.).  I promise your future self will send a Terminator robot back in time, to assassinate yourself, before the heinous act.